# Disabling edit on Telerick MVC Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Kendo UI Grid as follows

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeViewModel>()
              .Name("someGrid")
              .ToolBar(toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Create().Text("Add Entry");
                  toolbar.Save();
              })
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Name).ClientTemplate(@"<input type='radio' name='SomeradioName'> #= Name # </input>");
                  columns.Bound(p => p.DateCreated).Format("{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}");
              })
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
              .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
              .Events(e => e.Edit("onDataEdit"))
              .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
              .Scrollable()
              .Filterable()
              .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height:200px;"})
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .ServerOperation(false)
                  .Batch(false)
                  .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
                  .Model(model =>
                  {
                      model.Id(s => s.Id);
                      model.Field(s => s.Name).Editable(true);
                      model.Field(s => s.DateCreated).Editable(false);
                  })
                  .Read(read => read.Action(...))
                  .Create(create => create.Action(...))
                  .Update(create => create.Action(...))))
```

**I want to disable In cell editing for already added entries.**

So, couple of things I tried

**Approach# 1:**

```
<script>
    function onDataEdit(e) {
        if (!e.model.isNew()) {
            var grid = this;
            grid.closeCell();            
        }
    }
</script>
```

Apparently this breaks the radio button selection event (.change event) which is wired up in OnDataBound.`closeCell` screws it up and change event no longer gets fired up

**Approach# 2:**
In OnDataEdit event do

```
$("#Name").attr("readonly", true);
```

This is also fine but again Change event is no longer fired on radio button click until the `Cancel` changes command is clicked.

**Approach# 3**

There seems to be another way of doing it by disabling enable as given in this link here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit

```
if (!e.model.isNew()) {
      // Disable the editor of the "id" column when editing data items
      var numeric = e.container.find("input[name=id]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
      numeric.enable(false);
    }
```

How do I do something similar in my case ? Couldn't get `data` resolved.

Any other ways ?

**Update**

**Approach# 4**

```
 e.container.find("input[name=Name]").each(function () { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") }); 
 var grid = this;
grid.cancelChanges();
```

This does not break the change event. However, the experience is not that great. If adding new record, if the user presses any other row the changes are canceled. They have to add new record and either hit Save or click anywhere except grid rows

Comment: If you want to disable the edit functionality then why are you using in-cell editing? In-cell editing only make sense when editing, not when adding. It's not very different from in-line editing when adding.

Comment: That is how Telerik has created this mess I believe. Ideally, Create and Edit must have been two separate operations. This way anybody could have supported only Create functionality with no Edit (or update). But this is not the case. If I want to support only Create functionality while not adding Edit it throws an error. Try it. That is why we are seeing questions like these on how to disable grid edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen approach 4 which I updated. IF anyone has any better ideas feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the columns `readonly` on edit, using Approach 3

```
    function edit(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
     $('[name="Name"]').attr("readonly", true);
    }
}
```

Also, your template doesnt have an `id=Name`, hence I doubt below will work for you. Instead find by `name` attribute as above

```
$("#Name").attr("readonly", true);
```

[Refer this link for more information](http://www.telerik.com/forums/column-readonly-in-edit-mode-but-editable-in-add-mode-)

Comment: I just checked from Chrome browser and looks like it does solve the edit issue (from IE you can still add text at the beginning which is a bug there).
However, this solution no longer raises the Change event. If cancel command is clicked then change event starts working again. So this is a hack and not a clean solution IMO.

Comment: Well, in that case, I think one way to go would be to make the grid non-editable and add a button outside grid to add new records. On click popup  a window and add a new record  on submit to the datasource/ database for that matter using ajax or something and rebind the grid.

Comment: Yup, but because their grid already came with validation, ajax call etc. it was easier to simply use it. I updated with approach# 4 which is what I am planning to go with unless someone has better solution